# Android toolbar back arrow with icon like WhatsApp

Tags: android, toolbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

How to display icon with back arrow in android toolbar like WhatsApp ?

I use below code to set back arrow & icon in toolbar.

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 toolbar.setLogo(icon);
```

but i got result as below image.

[image]

I want icon immediate next after back arrow. I don't want any gap between back arrow & icon like below image of WhatsApp.

[image]

How to set icon with back arrow in toolbar like WhatsApp ?

Comment: it will not answer but merging a back and an profil image is not a good idea in term of UX. You're result seems more appropriate if you add margin on thr right of the image

Comment: @HugoGresse I don't want to merge profile image with back arrow. I just want to put it next to arrow without any margin or padding gap.

Comment: Yes but it will reduce drastically the interaction size of the button, it contradict material guidelines and reduce accessibility

Answer (score 21):

As far as I Know,
**WhatsApp** is not using **App-compat Support Library Toolbar**,
**Whatsapp** is setting the Custom Action Bar using

```
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.conversation_actionbar);
```

Attached is the conversation_actionbar.xml , **Whatsapp** is using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@id/custom_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
android:clipChildren="false" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/back"
    style="@style/ActionBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_padding_material" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="?homeAsUpIndicator" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/conversation_contact_photo_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/conversation_contact_photo"
            android:layout_width="35.0dip"
            android:layout_height="35.0dip"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <View
            android:id="@id/transition_start"
            android:layout_width="35.0dip"
            android:layout_height="35.0dip" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@id/change_photo_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmallInverse"
            android:layout_width="35.0dip"
            android:layout_height="35.0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/conversation_contact"
    style="@style/ActionBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="0.0dip" >

    <com.whatsapp.TextEmojiLabel
        android:id="@id/conversation_contact_name"
        style="@style/Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle.Condensed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/conversation_contact_status_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/conversation_contact_status_prefix"
            style="@style/Theme.ActionBar.SubtitleTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingRight="3.5sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/conversation_last_seen"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/conversation_contact_status"
            style="@style/Theme.ActionBar.SubtitleTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="1.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**But I would suggest you to follow Materail Design Rules and use ToolBar of App-compat Support Library**,

You can get the following result as shown in the Picture below[image: xPxIA.png]

By using following code

**your_activity.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_chats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_conversation"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**toolbar_conversation.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
>
<!-- android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" will cause this Custom View to make ripple effect -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/conversation_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/conversation_contact_photo"
            android:layout_width="35.0dip"
            android:layout_height="35.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/conversation_image"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="0.0dip" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="shanraisshan"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="last seen 1 hour ago"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity.java**

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_chats);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("Toolbar","Clicked");
    }
});
```

Just wait for it, **Whatsapp** will shift to App-compat Support Library in future.

Comment: can u tell me after applying the custom layout . How do i change image on runtime??

Comment: Between arrow and icon there are more space.How to reduce the space and change the image in runtime??

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this result by creating a custom `Drawable` containing an arrow and image icon then add it to the toolbar `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable)` as shown below.

```
        setSupportActionBar(mBinding.toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Drawable drawable = new Drawable() {
            @Override
            public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

                int width = canvas.getWidth();
                int height = canvas.getHeight();

                Bitmap bMap = CircularImageView.getCircularBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.beautiful_eyes_small));    
                canvas.drawBitmap(bMap,(width-(bMap.getWidth())), (height/2)-(bMap.getHeight()/2), null);

                Bitmap bMap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bMap2,0, (height/2)-(bMap2.getHeight()/2), null);
            }

            @Override
            public void setAlpha(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

            }

            @Override
            public int getOpacity() {
                return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
            }
        };
        mBinding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable);
```

[image: Resulting toolbar]

Comment: I can't find CircularImageView class.

Answer (score 1):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

along with

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: It's not working for me. Margin gap between back arrow & icon is still exist,

Comment: are any of images has transparent parts around it please ensure that size of image as showed ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to set three of the action bar related values to display the icon:

`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_cast_dark);`

I would have thought that `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled' and 'setIcon` should have been enough but seems not.

I am using android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

You can set the padding of the Home Icon using the below code

```
((ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home)).setPadding(x, x, x, x);
x = set your value.
```

Comment: App crashed when using this code. NullPointerException at this line.

Comment: @Priyank are you using app-compat support library for your project ?

Comment: Yes, I am using `appcompat-v7-r22.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you should try to do some edits in back-button image like apply some conciseness reduce image width and also making it transparent. May be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this with the normal back arrow in toolbar because it has a 
minWidth 56dp with scaleType center you can do something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibCustomBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/yourImage"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pb" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and handle ibCustomBack by your self.