# How to have toolbar icon the way whatsapp has in android

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am trying put image exactly with the back button of toolbar. But i don't know how to achieve it. The closest i got was this :

[image]
but this is not nearly what i want. I want it exactly with the back button meaning that the back button and the image combined should be equal to the back button. So how do i achieve this??

[image]

my code was pretty simple :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setLogo(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.group_image));
```

So can someone please help me.

Comment: There seems to be some ordering bug. Mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525229/toolbar-navigation-icon-never-set
Probably you'll get some info here

Comment: ok i'll try that but one question . what's the difference between and icon and logo??

Comment: nope , didn't work for me . Different problem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
```

Comment: follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788678/android-toolbar-back-arrow-with-icon-like-whatsapp)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom view for your action bar and set that view.

```
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.conversation_actionbar);
```

Comment: if i have an imageview , how do i put my image on it at runtime?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29