# Custom image instead of logo in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-homebutton

How to set logo icon of an ActionBar to be a custom image? Similar as how it works on Whatsapp? I have tried to implement but its looking like this..[image]

How to remove the space?

I used like this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.dummy_user_profile_pic);
```

and in manifest

```
<application
        android:logo="@drawable/dummy_user_profile_pic"
```

What im doing wrong? please guide me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share contents of `dummy_user_profile_pic`?

Comment: that is png image

Comment: i think problem is with that image ...i have changed the right space went.. but  between arrow and image, space is showing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788678/android-toolbar-back-arrow-with-icon-like-whatsapp) and i can able to achieve it. But the space between home and image is default space comes from **App-compat Support Library Toolbar** Where as in **Whatsapp** there is no space. I think they didn't use **Support Library Toolbar**. You can see the default space when you provide the tittle to actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> setLogo(R.drawable.dummy_user_profile_pic);

in your code instead of

> setIcon(R.drawable.dummy_user_profile_pic);

and it should work just fine.

Comment: ya 1st i tried with SetLogo only its not worked.. Then i changed to SetIcon, this also not working..

Comment: Try using:
'getActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.dummy_user_profile_pic);' in your code.

Comment: android:icon="@drawable/dummy_user_profile_pic"  // Sorry for three comments .. I just started using this .. I'am getting familier to this

Comment: In manifest file under application we cant give it as icon, icon refers to app launcher icon..and i tried getActionBar its not working still space is there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788678/android-toolbar-back-arrow-with-icon-like-whatsapp i referred this link and achieved but here also space is there between arrow and image.. In whatsapp there is no space...

Answer (score 0):

```
   With toolbar you can easily customize actionbar as shown below 

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

      <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Sample"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/title_textview"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Note : don't use `getSupportactionbar.setTitle()` method while using this
just set the text of the textview inside the toolbar

Comment: same like this is used in that link which i mentioned... check for include layout under toolbar widget...